# Coloring Stripcharts in R

Tags: r

How do I change the colors of certain points using `ifelse` and lattice's `stripchart()`? I can create the following dotplot using `stripchart(d, method="stack", offset=1, pch=19, at=1.0)`:

[image]

I can also change the color of the plot using the parameter `col`, but I'm trying to do something more complicated, like this: `ifelse(d>40, "Red", "Black")`. (In this example, all dots less than or equal to 40 are black and everything above 40 is red.) How do I apply `ifelse` to this plot?

Comment: I am not sure it is as easy as this with stripchart()...

Comment: It isn't. I can get the colors to work if I use dotplot(), but then I can't get the dots to stack up....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest thing is to write a simple script to do the math and plot the stripchart using the standard plot() function

```
#generate some random numeric data     
set.seed(100)
    d <- sample(10:80, size = 150, replace = TRUE)

# count re-occurences of the same value (for plotting on the y-axis)
td <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(d), (function(i){ 
      c(d[i], 1+ sum(d[1:i] == d[i]))})))

# plot
plot(x= td[,1], y = td[,2], 
         pch=19, ylim = c(0, 20),
         col = ifelse(td[,1]>49, "red", "blue"))
```

[image]